# how can I only ignore files in a subdirectory via .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a file directory like below:

```
 --file1
     -lome.txt
    --file2
         -lome2.txt  
        --file3
             --lome3.txt
```

I want to ignore all files and subfiles inside the `file2` with `txt` extension but when I write `file2/*.txt` it only ignores `lome2.txt`, I know that's because `/` in `.gitignore` is for ignoring files only in that directory but I have no other choice for separating my folders (since `\` doesn't work). so, for accomplishing such a task what should I do?

Comment: Try `file2/*/*.txt`

Comment: it didn't work but file2/**/*.txt worked

Answer (score 1):

Put `.gitignore` in `file2` and in it just ignore `*.txt`. Like this:

```
echo "*.txt" > file2/.gitignore
```

`file2/.gitignore` works only in `file2`. Pattern `*.txt` makes Git to ignore all `*.txt` files (and directories) recursively.

Comment: it 's not a good practice to put .gitignore in a subdirectory, actually I found the solution...you can check the comment section

Comment: @alex_121 There is nothing wrong in putting `.gitignore` in a subdirectory, people do it frequently when they need it. For example to separate the top-level `.gitignore` that ignores build/compile artifacts and a `.gitignore` in `docs/` that ignores built docs.

Comment: @alex_121 Your `file2` seems to be a special subdirectory because you want to ignore `*.txt` only in it but not in the entire directory tree. So it only seems natural to put `.gitignore` inside the subdirectory and not at the root of the repo.

Comment: @alex_121 "not a good practice"? Why? What are the downsides?

Comment: I want to access to all my files and folders to evaluate which one should be ignored... If I place my `.gitignore` inside the `File 2`, I have no access to `File 1` anymore.@RomainValeri

Comment: @alex_121 You can have a different `.gitignore` at the root or in any subdirectory.

Comment: then, you don't think it's a little bit confusing to have two `.gitignore`...and it's not just better to use `file2/**/*.txt`

Comment: @alex_121 No, I don't think so. Not confusing at all for me.

Comment: ok then... @phd

Comment: Some repos have **lots** of `.gitignore` files at different levels. The behaviour is the same, and when you're not sure about what `.gitignore` is doing the ignoring of something, you always have `git check-ignore -v`